# Excel - Find all identical cells, sum separate cell in row for matches, output in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I've searched for an answer to this, but I can't find anything.  Hopefully some Excel guru out there has an easy answer.

CONTEXT

I have a sheet that has two columns; a list of airport codes (Col A) and a list of fuel gallons (Col B).  Column A has a bunch of duplicate entries, column B is always different.  It's basically a giant list of fill-up events for aircraft over time at different airports.  The airports can be the same, because it's one row per fill-up event.

PROBLEM

What I want to do is have a formula that takes the enter data set, finds all identical entries in Col A, sums the Col B values for the matches, and spits out the result on a separate sheet with one entry for every set/match.

OTHER STUFF

I do not have a reference list for Column A and I would rather not create one since there are thousands of entries.  I would like to just write a formula that does all this at once, using the data itself as the reference.

All the answers I find are "create a reference list on a separate sheet", and it's driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance for any help!

-rt

Comment: can you try pivot table?

Comment: I'd also like to avoid using the pivot table component, if only because I want to keep this straight formulas for our business team and not overly complicate things.  The issue I'm having is every solution is either "use a pivot table" or "have a reference col for the lookup on a separate sheet", and both of those are undesirable.  Im totally dumbfounded that there isn't an easy formula to just match within data and sum, it's a common business problem.

Comment: Say there are sets `(LGA, 5000),(LGA, 4000),(LGA, 2000)`, do you need to show `(LGA, 11000)` on the second sheet?

Comment: I think the answer is yes?  Basically I have a big spreadsheet with those two columns.  I might have 50 "LGA" rows in a set of 1000 rows, each of which has a separate count for fuel (e.g., LGA 100, LGA 172, LGA 895).  I need the function to 1) Look at column A (airport codes, e.g., LGA), find all duplicates/matches, sum all values for Column B for matched set, and then spit out the consolidated output with 1 entry for each set of matches with that SUM on a separate sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that you need a formula version of remove duplicated for column A, and a simple sumif for column B.

### Column A

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!A$1:A$1000,SMALL(IF(
 MATCH(Data!A$1:A$1000,Data!A$1:A$1000,0)=ROW(Data!A$1:A$1000),ROW(Data!A$1:A$1000)),ROW())),"")`

**Array Formula** so please press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** to complete it. After that you might see a `{}` outside the formula.

### Column B

`=SUMIF(Data!A$1:A$1000,A2,Data!B$1:B$1000)`

Just change the range for your data.

Reminders: The formula in columnA should starts from `Row#1`, or you have to add some offset constant for adjustments.

Since the returning value of `MATCH()` represents the position of the key in the given array. If we wanted it to be equal to its row number, we have to add some constant if the array is not started from `ROW#1`. So the adjustment of data in `Range(B3:B1000)` is below.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,SMALL(IF(
 MATCH('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,
 'Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,0)+2=ROW('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000),
 ROW('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000)),ROW())-2),"")
```

Further more, the range should exactly the same as the data range. If you need it larger than the data range for future expandability, an `IFERROR()` should added into the formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,SMALL(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(
 'Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,'Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,0)+2
 =ROW('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000),
 ROW('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000)),FALSE),ROW())-2),"")
```

Lastly, I truly recommended that you should use the `Remove Duplicated` built in excel since the array formula is about O(n^2) of time complexity and memory usage also. And every time you entered any data in even other cells, it will automatically re-calculate all formulas once the calculation option in your excel is automatic. *This will pull down the performance.*

Comment: Ah, okay, interesting.  Not sure why I didn't really think about the fact that I had to build that reference list implicitly as part of the consolidation.  So if I get you correctly, I'm doing a consolidation on Column A and then using that consolidated output (on my "Summary" sheet) to lookup and sum the matching values from Column B (on my data sheet)?

Comment: The question I have is how I get the "list" of outputs for the consolidation?  The formula only goes in one row obviously, will it dump the full consolidated list below it for me to reference?

Comment: I have trouble reading _consolidation_, maybe you should put the data you have and the output you wish as an example.

Comment: Hmm... not sure I understand the reference, I didn't see consolidation in your post?  For reference, my sheets are "Summary" and "Event Data".  I updated and inserted the formula you provided for Col A above, but it didn't return any value... just blank

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,SMALL(IF(
 MATCH('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,'Event Data'!B$3:B$1000,0)=ROW('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000),ROW('Event Data'!B$3:B$1000)),ROW())),"")

Comment: My data in Event Data starts at row 3, and column B is the airport codes.  Row 1000 is fine as a test since it'll tell me whether it's worth or not.  Right now it's just blank.  And yes, I saved it as an Array.

Comment: I had a reminder, read it please. And it's almost 4am in my time zone so I apologize for not being able to give response in next several hours.

Comment: Not sure I understand the offsets... is my setting the formula to start at B3 not an offset?

Comment: No, you only set the range without giving a offset constant. I'll edit my answer for data in `Range(B3:B1000)`.